# Search Box on Home Screen

Tags: android, search, android-searchmanager

I have used SearchManager and it provides search key only when app is launched. Is there a way to put a text box on the home screen/wallpaper and invoke activity when user presses enter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use widgets on the home screen, which you can have contain a textView and you can use an intent to launch an acticity you want on the press of enter - or any other event.