# Post Intent action from widget provider

Tags: android, android-widget, android-pendingintent, android-searchmanager

I want to [build a search widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375615/search-box-on-home-screen). Clicking on the widget should open search activity inside my  app. Here is the code from widget provider's onUpdate().

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
{
    /* as their may be many widget instances for this widget. we get an array. */
    for(int i=0;i< appWidgetIds.length; i++)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SearchActivity.class);
        intent.setAction("android.intent.action.SEARCH");
        PendingIntent pdIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), myPackage.R.layout.search_appwidget); 
        view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.search_widget_textbox,pdIntent );
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds[i], view);
    }

}
```

Inside my SearchActivity.onCreate(), I am checking for intent action as `Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals( this.getIntent().getAction())`. However, when an intent is posted using PendingIntent via widget provider the `this.getIntent().getAction()` returns null. When SearchActivity (which is a default SearchManager handler for the app) is invoked via SearchManager it gets valid action as `android.intent.action.SEARCH`.

What am I doing wrong with pending intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748590/clickable-widgets-in-android/2748723#2748723).
As it indicates the action is posted in SearchActivity.OnReceive(). Also the action is for text_box (not for activity) and hence `SearchActivity.getIntent().getAction()` is null.